# How to refer to the parameters in groovy pipeline script?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I merged this as `vars/gitCheckout.goovy` add this as library into the jenkins

```
def call(String branch = '*/master') {
  checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
      branches: [[name: ${branch}]],
      doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
      extensions: [[$class: 'SubmoduleOption',
                    disableSubmodules: false,
                    parentCredentials: false,
                    recursiveSubmodules: true,
                    reference: '',
                    trackingSubmodules: false]],
      submoduleCfg: [],
      userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://my-server.com/some/project.git']]])
}
```

Calling this method as below from jenkins Pipeline Script:

```
@Library('jenkins-library@master') _

pipeline {
  agent { label 'my-server' }
  stages {
    stage('Git Checkout') {
        steps {
        gitCheckout()
        }
  }
  }
}
```

This fails with error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method '$' found among steps [ArtifactoryGradleBuild, MavenDescriptorStep, ....`

I tried $branch, params.branch, but it didn't work, the code otherwise works if I don't use parameter and hardcode the branch name. Also, whenever I make any update to this .groovy script, should I test it by merging and running it as jenkins job? is there any other way to test before merging the groovy script ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `${branch}` in the 3rd line with just `branch`. You use `$` with a variable name when you e.g. interpolate variables inside Groovy strings:

```groovy
def value = "current branch is: ${branch}" // produces: current branch is */master
```

If you forgot to use `$` in string interpolation, nothing would happen:

```groovy
def value = "current branch is: branch" // produces: current branch is branch
```

Comment: Thanks, it works when I don't pass-in any argument, but when I try to call the function as `gitCheckout('some-sha')`, it fails with error `No signature of method: gitCheckout.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values`, I tried passing `gitCheckout('*/master')` for testing, still same error.

Comment: Check if you name the file correctly. I just noticed that you mentioned `vars/gitCheckout.goovy` in the question. Maybe that was just a typo in the text. The error suggests that `gitCheckout` custom vars cannot be found - it can be caused by an incorrect file name. The signature of the call function you shown looks fine.